# How to match anything but exclusively small letters?

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regex that will allow small letters alongside with other characters but not if there are only small letters.

e.g.

```
Example # would match
example # would not match
```

So a simple `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$` will not do the trick.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve, the last folder contains a city which is always in small letters, therefore a pattern I want to exclude:
https://regex101.com/r/gP1evZ/2

How can that be achieved in regex for python?

Comment: How about `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Z0-9 ][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$`. Then at least one character must be something other than a-z.

Comment: Is `EXAMPLE` a match?  Specifically, is something which has no lowercase letters at all a match?

Comment: Hm... interesting approch, I must admit I do not fully understand why this should work. Would the last two brackets not allow only one character?

Comment: Try `\b(?![a-z]+\b)\w+` https://regex101.com/r/liRU2H/1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes it would, the only no match is if the string only contains small characters.

Comment: Would an empty string match or not? Is it "yes, because it has no small letters" or "no, because it has no non-small letters"?

Comment: Try `^/(hunde|kleinanzeigen)/(?!.*/[a-z]+/).*(prp_[a-z0-9_]+_\d+|cat_48_5030.*)\.html$` https://regex101.com/r/kRvSS6/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow matching spaces, and the string should not contain only lower case chars or allow an empty string:

```
^(?![a-z ]+$)[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XPkOaS/1)

Or without the lookahead, match at least an uppercase char or digit

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eKNdKd/1)

**Edit**

For the updated data, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!.*/[a-z]+/)` to assert what is on the right is not only lowercase chars between forward slashes.

```
^/(hunde|kleinanzeigen)/(?!.*/[a-z]+/).*(prp_[a-z0-9_]+_\d+|cat_48_5030.*)\.html$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kRvSS6/1)

Or a bit broader match:

```
^/(hunde|kleinanzeigen)/(?!.*/[a-z]+/)\S+\.html$
```

Comment: Thank you, as there seem to be many possible solutions and integrating into my real live usage seems difficult, I have edited the question and added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation here:

```
^(?:[^a-z]+|(?=[^a-z]).+)$
```

### Demo

This regex says to match:

```
^(?:            from the start of the string
    [^a-z]+     all non lowercase letters
    |           OR
    (?=[^a-z])  assert that at least one non lowercase letter character appears
    .+          then match one or more of any type of character
)$              end of the string
```

Comment: Thank you, as there seem to be many possible solutions and integrating into my real live usage seems difficult, I have edited the question and added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try
^(?![a-z\s]*$)
this should match strings that do not contain only lowercase characters and whitespaces. Remove \s if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, as there seem to be many possible solutions and integrating into my real live usage seems difficult, I have edited the question and added an example.